# Proper way to release view in UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am building my own view in `loadView` of view controller. Just to check if I can release the view like below or there is anything else I will need to release it? I know framework will set it to nil once it requires to free up some memory.

```
- (void)loadView
{
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    [self.view release];
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks a bit weird, I'd do this instead:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
self.view = view;
[view release];
```

If you're using `@property (retain)` you don't have to worry about releasing it when it's set to nil e.g. `self.view = nil;`. However you should release it in `dealloc`.

Comment: So it's weird or incorrect? Do I have to `release` self.view in `dealloc` even if I don't overload `loadView`?

Comment: It's just weird. I suppose it works, I just wouldn't do it. You should release the view in dealloc no matter what; @synthesized properties don't do the final release for you.

Comment: That's really weird, because first of all memory management rule says if I don't own the object I don't have to release. In case if the self.view is created using nib file, then I don't own it, I guess. Second of all so far in Apple sample code I haven't seen releasing `self.view` in `dealloc` when view is created in Nib.

Comment: The way I see it, in the self.view accessor, any old view (if there is one) would first be released and then your newly alloced view would be set and retained. Since you are passing into the accessor a retained view it would end up with a retain count of 2. When this ViewController eventually goes away, the view would still remain in memory (with a retain count of 1) and leak. So you could pass self.view an autoreleased view (which is computationally wasteful) or just do what jtbandes suggests. Oh and [super dealloc] of UIViewController handles the releasing of the view normally.

Comment: Regardless — the new standard is to use [ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), which takes care of this problem entirely!

Answer (score 2):

The view property of a `UIViewController` will be released for you by the `UIViewController` itself. You are right however that when you create the view that you assign to a `UIViewController` you need to release it, but the way you are trying to do it is wrong. Either do what jtbandes suggest or simply:

```
self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)] autorelease];
```